# Jquery is not working after minification through asset plugin grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I am working on minifying the assets that are been used in my project.

I have installed Grails assets-plugin to minify the assets. But the every JS file that contains the Jquery code is not working, like `$(document).ready(function($) {});` isn't working and it shows the following error :-

```
xyz.unminified.js:1Uncaught TypeError: $(...).r is not a function
```

Don't know whats going on is there any way that to resolve the same?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you minification is not correctly set up. It changes the jQuery own names too, so your code will not work anymore.

Comment: @eisbehr then what approach do i follow to avoid that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know your minification program/grails. I just know that there are configurations for this in tools like `jsuglify`.

Comment: Try this plugin instead [link](https://grails.org/plugin/uglify-js-minified-resources)

Comment: @Abanoub its summary says that it works with the resource plugin and i am not using that plugin in my project i have used asset plugin.